# RxSwift Observe variable fields of struct type in array

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I have a problem with observing array of my custom type, that have a Variable fields. I want to create observable event, that will check, if value of this fields changed.
I have a struct:

```
struct Type {
    let name: Variable<String>
    let email: Variable<String>
}
```

And I have a array:

```
let array: Variable<[Type]>
```

All I need is Observable, that will return true, when field name count will be greater than 0. I try to play with Observable.combineLatest, but I cannot convert properly array.

Comment: You want to observe your variable `array` and return true if all elements have name.count greater than zero or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. This is what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should not be using `Variable` anymore, as it's deprecated. You should use `BehaviorRelay` instead.

I'm not sure I understand your question clearly. But you probably need something like this:

```
// namesNotEmpty will be true if all elements in array have name.count > 0
let namesNotEmpty: Observable<Bool> = array.asObservable()
  .flatMap { array -> Observable<[String]> in
    if array.isEmpty {
      // so that some event is emmited when array is empty
      return Observable.just([""])
    }

    return Observable.combineLatest(array.map { $0.name.asObservable() })
  }
  .map { array in
    array.filter { $0.isEmpty }.isEmpty
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, but isEmpty modifier cannot be used with Variable<String> field(BehaviorRelay too).

Comment: @MiXen Sorry, I'll update my answer, you have to use `$0.name.value.isEmpty`

Comment: That's strange, I update my variable, but the subscriber doesn't fire new events.

Comment: Oh, I understand your question now. I'll update my answer with hopefully working solution in a minute.

Comment: Yes, that is what I looking for, but I see that I have a problem, that observatories gets blocked, when main array is empty. Maybe do you know, what is wrong with it?

Comment: What do you mean they get blocked? When `array` is empty, the observable will not emit any events of course. But when you insert something to the `array` it will start emiting events again. You want to receive `false` if `array` is empty?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't say it clearly. Yes, I want to get a event false, when at initialization array is empty and array become empty.

Comment: Now is working in that way, that I need. Really thank you for help. I'll mark this answer.

Answer (score 0):

We know that `Variable` is deprecated and `Variable` is just a thin wrapper around a private instance of `BehaviorSubject` ([nice comment about that](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/487#issuecomment-185427309)). So, you can use `BehaviorSubject` instead.

Next thing, it's not good idea to put `Rx` type everywhere you want. The better way is to keep array and your `Rx` property separately.

For example:

```
struct CustomType {
    let name: String
    let email: String
}

private var array: [CustomType] = [] {
    didSet {
        if array.first(where: { $0.name.isEmpty }) == nil {
            subject.onNext(())
        }
    }
}

var subject = PublishSubject<Void>()

...

// and handle changes
subject.subscribe(onNext: {
    // logic
})
```

Here we have array of pure `CustomType` objects that trigger `subject` to send event when `if` condition is correct. This is much better and cleaner, because your logic is separated.

P.S. Also, if you not good at `*Subject`, i suggest you to google about it, because maybe your code need another sort of `*Subject`.

Comment: Sorry, but I really need Variable fields in struct, this solution is useless for me.